# Recover of a float variable from 4 bytes

Tags: c#, floating-point, byte

i want to transfer a float value from my bluetooth device to ma android app.
all data in the Bluetooth are transferred through byte. so the float value should be divided into 4 bytes.

[image]

the problem is that i don't know how to recover these 4 byte into a float value in my android app code.

for example the float value is equal to 29.2 and it's equivalent in binary = 41 E9 C4 F3.

so byte[0] = 0xF3 ; byte[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztimK.png) = 0xC4 ; byte[2] = 0xE9 ; byte[3] = 0x41 ;

here's what i did in my android app code in order to recover the float value :

```
float value;
value = ((byte[0]) | (byte[1] << 8) | (byte[2] << 16) | (byte[3] << 24));
```

and i tried the cast too but it doesn't work.

```
float value;
value = (float)((byte[0]) | (byte[1] << 8) | (byte[2] << 16) | (byte[3] << 24));
```

in fact when i do this the app read it as a 32 bit integer. it display me the value ‭1105839347‬ in decimal which is the equivalent in hexadecimal to 41E9C4F3.

but in reality i want to reconstitute the float value byte per byte.

how can i do it ?

**FI** : i code my android app using C# / xamarin

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BitConverter` class

```
var f = BitConverter.ToSingle(byteArray, 0);
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jIRK3h

You can read `BitConverter.ToSingle` documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.BitConverter.ToSingle/p/System.Byte[]/System.Int32/).